# Javascript background changer no working

Tags: javascript, image, background

I want to implement a background image changer in my code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my JS:

```
function XAX() {
    var P = document.getElementById("background1");
    var O = document.getElementById("background2");
    var I = document.getElementById("background3");
    if {P.checked === true} {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(Gates.jpg)";
    }
    else if {O.checked === true} {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(City.jpg)";
    }
    else if {I.checked === true} {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(forest.jpg)";
    }
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <input type="radio" id="background1" name="background" >Gates of Argonath</input><br>
    <input type="radio" id="background2" name="background" >Minas Tirith</input><br>
    <input type="radio" id="background3" name="background" >Rivendell</input><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="XAX()">
```

Comment: What is not working, what is the issue? Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: Cmon, take a closer look at the if statements. `if (condition) { do something }`. This is your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find correct code below

```
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="radio" id="background1" name="background" >Gates of Argonath</input><br>
    <input type="radio" id="background2" name="background" >Minas Tirith</input><br>
    <input type="radio" id="background3" name="background" >Rivendell</input><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="XAX()">
    <body>
    <script>
    function XAX() {
        var P = document.getElementById("background1");
        var O = document.getElementById("background2");
        var I = document.getElementById("background3");
        if (P.checked == true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(Gates.jpg)";
        }
        else if (O.checked == true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(City.jpg)";
        }
        else if (I.checked == true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(forest.jpg)";
        }
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

you are using `{` after if and else if statement, you should use `(`

Answer (score 1):

```
if {P.checked === true} {
//TODO
}
```

You should use this directly on if block because element.checked return the Boolean result and you should handle this directly on if block their is no need to check either element.checked=== true || element.checked === 1.

Here is my fiddle check this

https://jsfiddle.net/DeMaiz/tn6thygq/